# convert tree structure json to linear json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

here I have a tree of objects like the following, perhaps created using the excellent algorithm

```
 tableList = [
      {
        repo_id: 1,
        databasename: "IES",
        repo_name: "IES.dbo.BuildVersion",
        schema_name: "dbo",
        table_name: "BuildVersion",
        column_name: [
          "Database Version",
          "ModifiedDate",
          "SystemInformationID",
          "VersionDate",
          "datetime",
        ],
        datatype: ["nvarchar", "datetime", "tinyint", "datetime", "tinyint"],
      },
    ];
```

and the datatype values and the column_name values are correspondent to each other i mean,,column_name :Database Version is of datatype "nvarchar" and so on.
so how can i convert it to flat array of objects like below

```
tableList = [
  {
    repo_id: 1,
    databasename: "IES",
    repo_name: "IES.dbo.BuildVersion",
    schema_name: "dbo",
    table_name: "BuildVersion",
    column_name: "Database Version",
    datatype: "nvarchar",
  },
  {
    repo_id: 1,
    databasename: "IES",
    repo_name: "IES.dbo.BuildVersion",
    schema_name: "dbo",
    table_name: "BuildVersion",
    column_name: "ModifiedDate",
    datatype: "tinyint",
  },
  {
    repo_id: 1,
    databasename: "IES",
    repo_name: "IES.dbo.BuildVersion",
    schema_name: "dbo",
    table_name: "BuildVersion",
    column_name: "SystemInformationID",
    datatype: "tinyint",
  },
  {
    repo_id: 1,
    databasename: "IES",
    repo_name: "IES.dbo.BuildVersion",
    schema_name: "dbo",
    table_name: "BuildVersion",
    column_name: "VersionDate",
    datatype: "datetime",
  },
  {
    repo_id: 1,
    databasename: "IES",
    repo_name: "IES.dbo.BuildVersion",
    schema_name: "dbo",
    table_name: "BuildVersion",
    column_name: "datetime",
    datatype: "tinyint",
  }
];
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: Please add details - What is the bug? Also, edit the json result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) statement.

```js
tableListReformatted = tableList[0].datatype.map( (datatype, index) => {

  const {
    repo_id,
    databasename,
    repo_name,
    schema_name,
    table_name
  } = tableList[0] 

  return {
    repo_id,
    databasename,
    repo_name,
    schema_name,
    table_name,
    column_name: tableList[0].columnName[index],
    datatype
  }

})
```

If you wanted to flatten a `tableList` that has many entries, you could do this process for each entry and push the results to an array:

```js
// create empty array to start
const tableListReformatted = []

tableList.forEach( listItem => {

  // for each item in the tableList, create an array
  // of objects which is mapped from the .datatype property
  const flattenedItems = listemItem.dataType.map( (datatype, index) => {

    return {
      ...listItem // use all the existing properties
      column_name: listItem.columnName[index], // overwrite column_name
      datatype // overwrite datatype
    }

  })

  // spread that array into the empty starter array
  tabeListeReformatted.push(...flattenedItems)

})
```

This may need some tweaking, but your question is relatively simple and this is all great array-manipulation practice.

Comment: actually there are multiple objects in the tree json, so does this solution work if there are multiple objects.

Comment: This exact solution won't work, but you can get creative with your `.map` statements to achieve that result.  If I have time I'll come back to this, but give it a shot on your own now that you see how `.map` can be leveraged.

Comment: Ok I added a solution to the answer that addresses a case where `tableList` has many entries

Comment: This works great,, thank you for the help. Looks tricky, but the solution provided is simple and great Thanks Again :).

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer helped you please mark it as the answer so we reduce the number of unanswered questions.  Also I always appreciate a good upvote.